# Can ElementTree be told to preserve the order of attributes?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I've written a fairly simple filter in python using ElementTree to munge the contexts of some xml files. And it works, more or less.

But it reorders the attributes of various tags, and I'd like it to not do that.

Does anyone know a switch I can throw to make it keep them in specified order?

### Context for this

I'm working with and on a particle physics tool that has a complex, but oddly limited configuration system based on xml files. Among the many things setup that way are the paths to various static data files. These paths are hardcoded into the existing xml and there are no facilities for setting or varying them based on environment variables, and in our local installation they are necessarily in a different place.

This isn't a disaster because the combined source- and build-control tool we're using allows us to shadow certain files with local copies. But even thought the data fields are static the xml isn't, so I've written a script for fixing the paths, but with the attribute rearrangement diffs between the local and master versions are harder to read than necessary.

---

This is my first time taking ElementTree for a spin (and only my fifth or sixth python project) so maybe I'm just doing it wrong.

Abstracted for simplicity the code looks like this:

```
tree = elementtree.ElementTree.parse(inputfile)
i = tree.getiterator()
for e in i:
    e.text = filter(e.text)
tree.write(outputfile)
```

Reasonable or dumb?

---

Related links:

- [How can I get the order of an element attribute list using Python xml.sax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998514/how-can-i-get-the-order-of-an-element-attribute-list-using-python-xml-sax)
- [Preserve order of attributes when modifying with minidom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662624/preserve-order-of-attributes-when-modifying-with-minidom)

Comment: is there no real solution to this? etree in python 3.4 does not preserve attributes? or does it with some settings??
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Gabriel Look at the accepted answer...

Comment: i thought of an non-monkey-patch solution =)?
sadly as it looks there is nothing better for now...
this question is especially relevant if the XML should stay hand-editable, and user-friendy to read, I almost think I am going for regex substitutions to modify the xml, sucks but, the layout is then preserved (also formattings like indentations and linebreaks)

Comment: If your goal is a reasonable diff, consider keeping the canonical copy of your file in [c14n](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n) format. That way you can re-canonicalize any modified version and get a diff that only includes semantically-relevant changes.

Comment: It isn't documented anywhere, but apparently python 3.8 fixes this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With help from @bobince's answer and these two ([setting attribute order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257978/elementtree-setting-attribute-order), [overriding module methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829200/override-module-method-where-from-import-is-used))

I managed to get this monkey patched it's dirty and I'd suggest using another module that better handles this scenario but when that isn't a possibility:

```
# =======================================================================
# Monkey patch ElementTree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def _serialize_xml(write, elem, encoding, qnames, namespaces):
    tag = elem.tag
    text = elem.text
    if tag is ET.Comment:
        write("<!--%s-->" % ET._encode(text, encoding))
    elif tag is ET.ProcessingInstruction:
        write("<?%s?>" % ET._encode(text, encoding))
    else:
        tag = qnames[tag]
        if tag is None:
            if text:
                write(ET._escape_cdata(text, encoding))
            for e in elem:
                _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
        else:
            write("<" + tag)
            items = elem.items()
            if items or namespaces:
                if namespaces:
                    for v, k in sorted(namespaces.items(),
                                       key=lambda x: x[1]):  # sort on prefix
                        if k:
                            k = ":" + k
                        write(" xmlns%s=\"%s\"" % (
                            k.encode(encoding),
                            ET._escape_attrib(v, encoding)
                            ))
                #for k, v in sorted(items):  # lexical order
                for k, v in items: # Monkey patch
                    if isinstance(k, ET.QName):
                        k = k.text
                    if isinstance(v, ET.QName):
                        v = qnames[v.text]
                    else:
                        v = ET._escape_attrib(v, encoding)
                    write(" %s=\"%s\"" % (qnames[k], v))
            if text or len(elem):
                write(">")
                if text:
                    write(ET._escape_cdata(text, encoding))
                for e in elem:
                    _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
                write("</" + tag + ">")
            else:
                write(" />")
    if elem.tail:
        write(ET._escape_cdata(elem.tail, encoding))

ET._serialize_xml = _serialize_xml

from collections import OrderedDict

class OrderedXMLTreeBuilder(ET.XMLTreeBuilder):
    def _start_list(self, tag, attrib_in):
        fixname = self._fixname
        tag = fixname(tag)
        attrib = OrderedDict()
        if attrib_in:
            for i in range(0, len(attrib_in), 2):
                attrib[fixname(attrib_in[i])] = self._fixtext(attrib_in[i+1])
        return self._target.start(tag, attrib)

# =======================================================================
```

Then in your code:

```
tree = ET.parse(pathToFile, OrderedXMLTreeBuilder())
```

Comment: Wow. In the years since I asked this question the offending tool has been re-structured to allow persistent local overrides so that my original need has disappeared and I've moved on to different, if not greener, pastures and don't even use the fixed version any more. None the less, I am sure that *someone* still has this need.

Comment: @dmckee : you are totally right. [This question is still relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587264/original-order-of-processed-xml-with-elementtree-cant-be-kept?noredirect=1#comment51129714_31587264) and the patch can't be the correct way to solve this .

Comment: is there a solution now for python 3.4? Did the etree implementation change to allow this?

Comment: "Another module that better handles this scenario" Do you have any specific ones in mind?

Comment: **Note**: patching `ET._serialize_xml` is NOT enough if you want root node atributes to preserve the order as well! Also put the patched `_serialize_xml` into `ET._serialize['xml']` and Voilà you got that too!! :]

Comment: The answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/47422944/500902 is a much simpler "monkey-patch" to preserve the output order.  I point out this does not fix round trip issues (parsing into element tree then outputting) but I thik neither does this answer.

Answer (score 19):

Nope. ElementTree uses a dictionary to store attribute values, so it's inherently unordered.

Even DOM doesn't guarantee you attribute ordering, and DOM exposes a lot more detail of the XML infoset than ElementTree does. (There are some DOMs that do offer it as a feature, but it's not standard.)

Can it be fixed? Maybe. Here's a stab at it that replaces the dictionary when parsing with an ordered one ([`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects)).

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from collections import OrderedDict
import StringIO

class OrderedXMLTreeBuilder(ElementTree.XMLTreeBuilder):
    def _start_list(self, tag, attrib_in):
        fixname = self._fixname
        tag = fixname(tag)
        attrib = OrderedDict()
        if attrib_in:
            for i in range(0, len(attrib_in), 2):
                attrib[fixname(attrib_in[i])] = self._fixtext(attrib_in[i+1])
        return self._target.start(tag, attrib)

>>> xmlf = StringIO.StringIO('<a b="c" d="e" f="g" j="k" h="i"/>')

>>> tree = ElementTree.ElementTree()
>>> root = tree.parse(xmlf, OrderedXMLTreeBuilder())
>>> root.attrib
OrderedDict([('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('j', 'k'), ('h', 'i')])
```

Looks potentially promising.

```
>>> s = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> tree.write(s)
>>> s.getvalue()
'<a b="c" d="e" f="g" h="i" j="k" />'
```

Bah, the serialiser outputs them in canonical order.

This looks like the line to blame, in `ElementTree._write`:

```
            items.sort() # lexical order
```

Subclassing or monkey-patching that is going to be annoying as it's right in the middle of a big method.

Unless you did something nasty like subclass `OrderedDict` and hack `items` to return a special subclass of `list` that ignores calls to `sort()`. Nah, probably that's even worse and I should go to bed before I come up with anything more horrible than that.

Comment: Very nice OrderedXmlTreeBuilder in code above! It can be used with ltree and serialization will be fixed too. Thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 13):

Best Option is to use the **lxml** library http://lxml.de/
Installing the lxml and just switching the library did the magic to me.

```
#import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree as ET
```

Comment: thdox already [posted that suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34560411/2509).

Comment: @dmckee : you are right. I totally missed that answer.

Comment: It did work for me as well, Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, with [lxml](http://lxml.de/)

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> root = etree.Element("root", interesting="totally")
>>> etree.tostring(root)
b'<root interesting="totally"/>'
>>> print(root.get("hello"))
None
>>> root.set("hello", "Huhu")
>>> print(root.get("hello"))
Huhu
>>> etree.tostring(root)
b'<root interesting="totally" hello="Huhu"/>'
```

Here is direct [link](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-carry-attributes-as-a-dict) to documentation, from which the above example is slightly adapted.

Also note that lxml has, by design, some good API compatiblity with standard [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Comment: Are you sure that lxml preserves the attribute order? The documentation seems to say the opposite.

Comment: From the documentation, I simplified the example, and tried it with my python 3.4, and the example provided here is pasted from my terminal. At least it worked for me. Also the documentation, at least the url I provided, clearly states that it preserves order, not the lexical order, but the order asked in this stackoverfow question.

Comment: No offence, but the question is about preserving the order of the attributes of an element. The documentation of lxml (on your link) says: "Attributes are just unordered name-value pairs...". I did not find anything about preserving the order of element attributes from the XML source. The tricky part of the question is that the author has more strict needs than those that are guaranteed by XML format -- which is understandable, but probably not implemented by lxml.

Comment: My understanding of "Attributes are just unordered name-value pairs..." is, contrary to xml.etree.ElementTree who is ordering by lexical order, lxml is able to keep the non-lexical order, that is something like the FIFO order here.
When you say "I did not find anything about preserving the order of element attributes from the XML source.", I would read the xml file with lxml (note the 'l'), and when writing, I would explicitely chose the order I want, using above example.

Comment: Is the preserving the order of element attributes documented for lxml? I did not find it, and I cannot rely on any guess based on any observation.

Comment: This seems to work in my experience.  I've just been writing a script to alter the AndroidManifest.xml file in .apk files and lxml.etree preserves the attribute order while xml.etree.ElementTree doesn't.  As an added bonus it also preserves namespace alias names (which xml.etree.ElementTree fails to do)!  Gets top marks from me.....

Answer (score 6):

This has been "fixed" in python 3.8. I can't find any notes about it anywhere, but it works now.

```
D:\tmp\etree_order>type etree_order.py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

a = ET.Element('a', {"aaa": "1", "ccc": "3", "bbb": "2"})

print(ET.tostring(a))
D:\tmp\etree_order>C:\Python37-64\python.exe etree_order.py
b'<a aaa="1" bbb="2" ccc="3" />'

D:\tmp\etree_order>c:\Python38-64\python.exe etree_order.py
b'<a aaa="1" ccc="3" bbb="2" />'
```

Comment: This is not mentioned in [What’s New In Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html), but it is mentioned in the documentation for the `tostring()`, `tostringlist()` and `dump()` functions and the `write()` method.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) for `ElementTree.write` method states: _"Changed in version 3.8: The write() method now preserves the attribute order specified by the user."_

Answer (score 5):

Wrong question. Should be: "Where do I find a `diff` gadget that works sensibly with XML files?

Answer: Google is your friend. First result for search on "xml diff" => [this](http://diffxml.sourceforge.net/). There are a few more possibles.

Comment: Always happy to see an alternate solution. Thanks.

Comment: In a perfect world, yes.  However, sometimes we don't get to choose all the components of our toolset--for example, if your version control system can't be taught to diff XML files semantically, and you can't change to a different one.

Comment: How do I integrate the tool with Github, Stash or any other web interface to a version control system?

Comment: In many cases xml files are just obscure artifacts in a Git repository. It then is more sensible imo to minimize the default diff than requre the entire work group to install a tool to handle a dying file format. My responsibility in a team is not to mess up all the other members diffs. That is not done by requiring them to install a special tool. 

So I disagree regarding the original questions usefullness.

Answer (score 3):

From section 3.1 of [the XML recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/):

> Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant.

Any system that relies on the order of attributes in an XML element is going to break.

Comment: This is not necessarily about correctness, but about maintaining minimal diff.

Answer (score 3):

This is a partial solution, for the case where xml is being emitted and a predictable order is desired. It does not solve round trip parsing and writing.   Both 2.7 and 3.x use `sorted()` to force an attribute ordering.  So, this code, in conjunction with use of an OrderedDictionary to hold the attributes will preserve the order for xml output to match the order used to create the Elements.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

# Make sorted() a no-op for the ElementTree module
ET.sorted = lambda x: x

try:
    # python3 use a cPython implementation by default, prevent that
    ET.Element = ET._Element_Py
    # similarly, override SubElement method if desired
    def SubElement(parent, tag, attrib=OrderedDict(), **extra):
        attrib = attrib.copy()
        attrib.update(extra)
        element = parent.makeelement(tag, attrib)
        parent.append(element)
        return element
    ET.SubElement = SubElement
except AttributeError:
    pass  # nothing else for python2, ElementTree is pure python

# Make an element with a particular "meaningful" ordering
t = ET.ElementTree(ET.Element('component',
                       OrderedDict([('grp','foo'),('name','bar'),
                                    ('class','exec'),('arch','x86')])))
# Add a child element
ET.SubElement(t.getroot(),'depend',
              OrderedDict([('grp','foo'),('name','util1'),('class','lib')]))  
x = ET.tostring(n)
print (x)
# Order maintained...
# <component grp="foo" name="bar" class="exec" arch="x86"><depend grp="foo" name="util1" class="lib" /></component>

# Parse again, won't be ordered because Elements are created
#   without ordered dict
print ET.tostring(ET.fromstring(x))
# <component arch="x86" name="bar" grp="foo" class="exec"><depend name="util1" grp="foo" class="lib" /></component>
```

The problem with parsing XML into an element tree is that the code internally creates plain `dict`s which are passed in to Element(), at which point the order is lost.  No equivalent simple patch is possible.

Comment: it woks for me. and simple enough!

Answer (score 2):

Have had your problem. Firstly looked for some Python script to canonize, didnt found anyone. Then started thinking about making one. Finally [`xmllint`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xmllint)solved.

Comment: In those days since then have had kinda similar problem with rdf (an xml subset) which i solve with inner views and sorting alphabetically that views.

Answer (score 0):

I used the accepted answer above, with both statements:

```
ET._serialize_xml = _serialize_xml
ET._serialize['xml'] = _serialize_xml
```

While this fixed the ordering in every node, attribute ordering on new nodes inserted from copies of existing nodes failed to preserve without a deepcopy.  Watch out for reusing nodes to create others...
In my case I had an element with several attributes, so I wanted to reuse them:

```
to_add = ET.fromstring(ET.tostring(contract))
to_add.attrib['symbol'] = add
to_add.attrib['uniqueId'] = add
contracts.insert(j + 1, to_add)
```

The `fromstring(tostring)` will reorder the attributes in memory.  It may not result in the alpha sorted dict of attributes, but it also may not have the expected ordering.

```
to_add = copy.deepcopy(contract)
to_add.attrib['symbol'] = add
to_add.attrib['uniqueId'] = add
contracts.insert(j + 1, to_add)
```

Now the ordering persists.

Comment: reusing a node? I wasn't able to comment so I added it as a complement to the accepted answer.  It is to caution anyone that also wants to copy an existing and insert it with some values changed back into the tree.  If one wants to do this, the accepted answer fails without a deepcopy.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using LXML (as others have as well).  If you need to preserve the order of attributes to adhere to the c14n v1 or v2 standards (https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n2/) (i.e. increasing lexicographic order), lxml supports this very nicely by passing an output method (see heading C14N of https://lxml.de/api.html)

For example:

```
from lxml import etree as ET 
element = ET.Element('Test', B='beta', Z='omega', A='alpha') 
val = ET.tostring(element, method="c14n") 
print(val)
```

Answer (score -2):

By running the python script in python 3.8 version we can preserve the order of the attributes in xml files.

Comment: There is no new information here. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60176826/407651.