# In Python, is there an easy way to edit xml in place?

Tags: python, xml

Suppose I want to edit a node in xml  and edit one of its attributes. I want to be able to do a simple file diff to just see one row changed. Dumping the xml using prettyprint changes the whole xml structure.

Answer (score 1):

Well then don't use prettyprint.

In `xml.dom.minidom` for example, if you do

```
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(inputfile)
do_something_with(doc)
outputfile.write(doc.toxml("utf-8").decode("utf-8"))
```

all the structure/whitespace etc. will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Consider NOT using "a simple file diff". [See this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741480/can-elementtree-be-told-to-preserve-the-order-of-attributes/2741886#2741886).