# XML tags generated in the wrong order

Tags: python, elementtree

thanks for your time. I'm trying to create an xml file and upload it into an application but for some reason it wont accept the file unless the name space is in the correct order. When creating the dictionary, the names and URIs are in the right order but when I use them in the ET.Element function as a dict, the order seems to change. I've tried just adding the dictionary instead of the dict(**ns) but it doesn't work.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
som='som'
cmn='cmn'
xsi='xsi'
ns = {'xlmns:som':som, 'xlmns:cmn':cmn,'xlmns:xsi':xsi}
for attr, uri in ns.items():
   ET.register_namespace(attr.split(":")[1],uri)
data = ET.Element('tagname', dict(**ns))
```

edit: sorry, forgot to add the code!

The desired output is `<tagname xlmns:som='som' xlmns:cmn='cmn' xlmns:xsi='xsi'><tagname>`

The output I'm getting is `<tagname xlmns:cmn="cmn" xlmns:som="som" xlmns:xsi="xsi">`

Comment: We love that you're here with us and we need a reproduce-able example.

Comment: @nicomp, hey sorry! I forgot to add the code!

Comment: Is your code indented correctly? What is the current and expected output? I this a [mcve]? Looks like import statements and data are missing. Make it easy to help you with a [mcve]...

Comment: What modules you have imported before writing the code ?
It's useful for members who will provide you proper solutions/suggestions.
Also, mention the real output and your expected output in the question.

Comment: @SalilTamboli, I have used the ElementTree module

Comment: In Python 3.8, the attribute order specified by the user is preserved: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write. If you use an older version of Python, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2741480/407651

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc 
som='som'
cmn='cmn'
xsi='xsi'
ns = {'xlmns:som':som, 'xlmns:cmn':cmn,'xlmns:xsi':xsi}
doc = SimplifiedDoc('<tagname></tagname>')
tag = doc.tagname
tag.setAttrs(ns)
# print (doc.html)
tag.insertAfter("<nexttag></nexttag>")
tag.setContent("test")
print (doc.html)
```

Result:

```
<tagname xlmns:som="som" xlmns:cmn="cmn" xlmns:xsi="xsi">test</tagname><nexttag></nexttag>
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples