# How to change the order of node attributes in xml?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

When creating an `xml` file using python, is it possible to change the order of the `attributes` of the `nodes`?

```
root = ET.Element("testsuites")
suite = ET.SubElement(
    root,
    "testsuite",
    {
        "name": "ABC",
        "Suit_id": "1234",
        "Suit_total_tests": "12",
        "Suit_failures": "2",
        "Suit_log": "Log",
    },
)
xmlstr = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root)).toprettyxml(indent="   ")
with open("Test.xml", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(xmlstr)
```

I get

`<testsuite Suit_failures="0" Suit_id="12" Suit_log="Log" Suit_total_tests="12" name="ABC">`

Desired Output:-

`<testsuite name="ABC" Suit_id="12" Suit_log="Log" Suit_total_tests="12" >`

I read about this and see that the order does not matter or one should not be expecting such ordering. In other cases I see it is possible using `Etree` or `Ordered Keys`. However, I couldn't figure out how to apply that here. Some clarity would help. Thanks.

Comment: What version of Python do you use? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60176826/407651

Comment: @mzjn Python 3.7

Comment: OK. There are multiple answers for different versions of Python in the linked question.  This is a duplicate.